# how to make Android listview scrolling under transparent textview. please

Tags: android, listview, textview, transparent

I wish `listView` to scroll partly under transparent `textView` on which I want set some items.

But `listView` area just borders `textView` area.

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView        
        android:id="@+id/appLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#00000000"  
   />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```